# Google Map Street View not loading in Internet Explorer

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, google-maps, iframe

I'm working on a virtual tour module for a website I've created. I used adobe edge animate for this, wanting to ensure that i would be up to standards and cross browser friendly, including IOS. I worked out the whole module and have it working great on all browsers on my mac, and when I test it out on my pc, it works in every browser except internet explorer (ie 10).

The link for this is http://grandviewproducts.com/virtual-tour-test/

The module will load and the animation will work in IE, but the street view of the map will not work. It looks like it gets stuck loading it, or really it looks like IE is not loading Flash within the Iframe.

On another page I have a single google map street view embed that works fine in IE, it's only the ones within this module that will not work.

Comment: Your [HTML is invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgrandviewproducts.com%2Fvirtual-tour-test%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: Ok I have reviewed this and gotten this page up to standards according to the validator. However, the street view google maps still will not load in IE10 and only work sometimes in Firefox. They open without any problems in Chrome and Safari. The link for the validated page is http://grandviewproducts.com/x1191/wp-content/themes/GVP-1.0/virtual-tour-test.html

Comment: Looks to me like IE doesn't compute a valid size for the StreetView container (it is acting like a zero size div, content in the upper left corner).

Comment: Ok so do you think that adding dimensions to the div will help it?

Comment: the only part i don't get about that is that using a single map will show up perfectly fine in all browsers. I'm using the embed code that google produces, which includes a width and height. On the same site I have a working one at http://grandviewproducts.com/live-tour/

Comment: Perhaps you need to trigger the [resize event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama) on the panorama when you unhide it?